# Threaded merge sort slower than serial implementation

Tags: c#, multithreading, mergesort

For school we got a task to create a multithreaded application. We chose to make a multithreaded implementation of merge sort.

We however can't manage to make it work faster than the serial implementation.

I have already tried the following:

- implementation with unlimited threads (code example 1) (was extremely slow)
- implementation with limited threads (code example 2) (4 threads max - still really slow)
- implementation using Parallel.Invoke (code example 3) (still slower)
- complex implementation also with a parallel merge function (just shamefully slow)

When I use the analyze tools in Visual Studio (Instrumentation part) I found the timings for the functions called and the threaded solution is always extremely slower than the serial implementation.

I can't see any possible reason for this.

(for example: with 5000000 numbers to sort; serial implementation: 16.717,17; parallel: 20.259,97; results with just 1 extra thread)

I tested it on both machines I own:

- Intel Core 2 Quad Q9450 @ 2.66Ghz
- Intel Core i7 Q720 @1.60Ghz

I can't for my life figure out how this is possible, shouldn't this just speed up the process?

I would be really greatefull if somebody would be able to help me out.

code example 1:

```
ParallelMerge pMerge = new ParallelMerge(T, p1, q1 -1, p2, q2-1, A, p3);
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(pMerge.parallel_merge));
thread.Start();

ParallelMerge pMerge2 = new ParallelMerge(T, q1 + 1, r1, q2, r2, A, q3 + 1);
pMerge2.parallel_merge();
thread.Join();
```

code example 2:

```
if(depthRemaining > 0)
{
   ParallelMerge pMerge = new ParallelMerge(T, p1, q1 -1, p2, q2-1, A, p3);
   thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(pMerge.parallel_merge));
   thread.Start();
   ParallelMerge pMerge2 = new ParallelMerge(T, q1 + 1, r1, q2, r2, A, q3 + 1);
   pMerge2.parallel_merge(); 
   thread.Join();
}
else
{
   ParallelMerge pMerge = new ParallelMerge(T, p1, q1 -1, p2, q2-1, A, p3);
   pMerge.parallel_merge(); 
   ParallelMerge pMerge2 = new ParallelMerge(T, q1 + 1, r1, q2, r2, A, q3 + 1);
   pMerge.parallel_merge(); 
}
```

code example 3:

```
if (depthRemaining > 0)
{
   Parallel.Invoke(
      () => threaded_merge_sort(getallen, p, q, depthRemaining-1));

   threaded_merge_sort(getallen, q + 1, r, 0);
}
else
{
   threaded_merge_sort(getallen, p, q, 0);
   threaded_merge_sort(getallen, q+1, r, 0);
}
```

Comment: Use the TPL (Parallel.Invoke) or the ThreadPool.

Comment: Tipically, the bottleneck of sorting problems are I/O operations, so parallelizing the computations does not lead to great performance improvements.

Comment: 50000 numbers is not very many. Continual thread create/join means a huge pile of avoidable overhead.  If you have a textbook that says that using threads requries creating them and then join()ing to wait for results, burn it.  Look at ThreadPool/TPL as suggested by @HenkHolterman.

Comment: I tried it with TPL as displayed in example 3. This doesn't rlly give me a lot of slower speed. But it doesn't give a speedup as well. I also notices i missed out a few zero's on the numbers there. It should be 5000000, edited it now.

Comment: Merge sorts are also better combined with an in-place sort on sub-lists of, say, CPU L1 cache-size.  The thought of spawning a thread to merge sublists of 2 items is horrifying.

Comment: Strange, this.  A merge sort is one algorithm where I would think that threading off the work to [no. of cores] threads would generate a useful speedup.  One thing - even if you find the probem and speed up your sort, it's not going to matter.  Your prof/tutor will take one brief glance at your code, pick up the red marker, draw a ring at the top, write 'F' in it, toss your submission on the 'failed' pile and move on to look at reports from students who did not use single-letter variable names :(

Comment: was gonna change up the one letter variables to longer vars, don't worry :)

Comment: @ArneClaerebout - the thing is, if your prof/tutor is not going to look at your work because he/she does not have the time to dig out how it works, what are you saying about the highly-skilled and experienced developers on SO?

Comment: @MartinJames point taken, my apologies, the reason why there are abreviations here is because these are the variables they use in the textbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it seems the problem wasn't with the code but with the analysing tools from VS.
>
> -Arne Claerebout

Answer (score 2):

What unit of time are you reporting in?

Starting a new thread is a 'slow' operation. Sorting/merging very short list using multi threading can be a bit slower.

If you just split the length of the number list in halve does the program run faster? if not you're code simply doesn't scale.

Answering this question without the actual code implementation is a bit hard to do.

Comment: the timings are in msec, I also noticed i missed a few zero's there. Should be 5000000 numbers.

I posted my code on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/LrSKrSW2